# Hide/Show checkbox fields depending on link (or checkbox) click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show/hide a specific set of checkbox fields (location fields) depending if the parent name is selected. Think - if "United States" is clicked, all US locations will show up below the United States label.

I've been playing with some Javascript - and I've got it to effectively display/remove the checkbox when the parent is selected / deselected, however I cannot get the label to follow suit.

I should note - I'm trying to add this script to a **Pardot form** which doesn't allow for customization of label ID's / Classes. The code below is set up exactly how it would appear on a Pardot form - I just need to remove the Checkboxes & Labels (ideally all spacing, but I'm not 100% sure if the spacing will be removed by the display:none's when the parent is not toggled)

I cannot append a class to a span as there are multiple spans on the form and several groupings that need to be toggled differently.

```
    <html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var divs = ["337691_9557pi_337691_9557_70203", "337691_9557pi_337691_9557_70205"];

function visiblox(arrDiv, hs) {
    var disp = (hs) ? "inline-block" : "none";
    for(var x = 0; x < arrDiv.length; x++) {
        document.getElementById(arrDiv[x]).style.display = disp;
    }
}

function chk(what, item) {
    if(item) {
        visiblox(what, true);
    } else {
        visiblox(what, false);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div> 
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="chk(divs, this.checked);"> Show/Hide all<br>
</div>
<div>
    <span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="337691_9557pi_337691_9557_70203" id="337691_9557pi_337691_9557_70203" value="70203" onchange="" style="display: none;">
            <label class="inline" for="337691_9557pi_337691_9557_70203">Testing 1</label>
    </span>
    <span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="337691_9557pi_337691_9557_70205" id="337691_9557pi_337691_9557_70205" value="70205" onchange="" style="display: none;">
        <label class="inline" for="337691_9557pi_337691_9557_70205">Testing 2</label>
    </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are doing 
    document.getElementById();
And in your code id is available in "input" tag not to the "label" tag. You can add a class to the span and toggle the content.

```
<span class="some-class">
     <input/>
     <label/>
</span>
```

Comment: I cannot add a class to the span tag as it's handled by Pardot. - Is there a way around this via javascript or jquery?  I understand your answer but it won't work with Pardot - at least I can't figure out how to get it to work.